Proof of De Moivre's Theorem Result
I read a proof of De Moivre's Theorem.
De Moivre's Theorem states that:
$$(r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta))^n = r^n(\cos(\theta n ) + i \sin(\theta n))$$
It is easy by the principle of mathematical induction، but how we can prove the result of this theorem where the result is :
$$z^{\frac{1}{a}} = r^{\frac{1}{a}} \left( \cos\left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{a}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{a}\right) \right)$$
for $ k=0,1,2,3,...,a-1 , z=x+yi $ .
I tried to prove by studying change in the argument, and I  thought of another question, which is :
As we add $ 2k\pi $ why do we get different values?
So, how we can prove this result above?

It is not clear what you are asking.

You have to define $z^{1/n},$ first. $z^n$ is easily defined by induction when $n$ is a non-negative integer, but there are $n$ different candidates for $z^{1/n}$ for $n$ an integer. You can easily prove the right hand is one of those candidates, but proving equality requires a more precise meaning for $z^{1/n}.$

@copper.hat ,  I edit question , I just need proof of the result

Basically, as written, this isn't true, because the right hand side can take multiple values, depending on $k,$ while the left side is a functional expression. You'd have to define the left side as a multivalued function to make it true. However the right hand side is all of the solutions $w$ for $w^n=z.$

Also, presumably, you mean $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).$ You should put that at the top of the question, especially since there is no $r$ or $\theta$ in your De Moivre beginning.)

Addendum-2 added to respond to the comment/question of
Azam Abdullah.

Arbitrarily, let $~e^{i\theta}~$ denote $~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).~$
Then, De Moivre's theorem is actually a consequence of the much stronger theorem that
$$\forall ~\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb{R}, ~e^{i\alpha} \times e^{i\beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}. \tag1 $$
A proof of (1) above is given in the Addendum, at the end of this answer.
Note:
Although for this particular problem, DeMoivre's theorem is sufficent, I prefer to work with the stronger theorem, given in (1) above.

What (1) above indicates is that you can multiply complex numbers together by adding their angles.

...how we can prove that:


$$z^{\frac{1}{a}} = r^{\frac{1}{a}} \left( \cos\left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{a}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{a}\right) \right)$$
for $ k=1,2,3...a-1 , z=x+yi $

I am assuming that you intend that $~z = r ~e^{i\theta},~$ 
where $~r \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~\theta \in \Bbb{R}.$
I am also assuming that the assertion that you are actually trying to prove is that for all $~a \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ the $~a~$ (distinct) roots of the equation $~w^a = z~$ are given by
$$w_k = r^{1/a} ~e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)/a} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,a-1\}. \tag2 $$
It is clear that, as defined in (2) above, that $~w_0, ~w_1, ~\cdots, ~w_{a-1}~$ are all distinct from each other.  Further, from basic Field theory, the equation $~w^a = z~$ can have no more than $~a~$ distinct roots.
Therefore, it is sufficient to show that for all $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,a-1\},~$ that
$$(w_k)^a = z. \tag3 $$
(3) above is actually an immediate consequence of (1) above.
That is,
$$(w_k)^a = [ ~r^{1/a} ~]^a \times \exp\{ ~[~i(\theta + 2k\pi)/a ~] \times a ~\} = r \exp\{ ~i(\theta + 2k\pi) ~\}$$
$$= r \exp\{i\theta\} = re^{i\theta} = z.$$
Note that in the demonstration above, the assumption that
$$e^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)}$$
is based on the idea that

$\cos(\theta) = \cos(\theta + 2k\pi).$

$\sin(\theta) = \sin(\theta + 2k\pi).$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
To prove:
$$\forall ~\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb{R}, ~e^{i\alpha} \times e^{i\beta} = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}. $$
To prove this, you first need the preliminary results that

$\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta).$

$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta).$


To establish the preliminary results above, you can consult the "Angle sum and difference identities" section of trigonometric identities.
Then
$$e^{i\alpha} \times e^{i\beta} = [ ~\cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha) ~] \times [ ~\cos(\beta) + i\sin(\beta) ~]$$
$$= [ ~\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) ~] + i ~[ ~\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta) ~]$$
$$= \cos(\alpha + \beta) + i\sin(\alpha + \beta) = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}.$$
Note that the above demonstration is based on the idea that
$$(r + is) \times (u + iv) = (ru - sv) + i(rv + su) ~: ~r,s,u,v \in \Bbb{R}.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum-2}}$
Responding to the comment/question of Azam Abdullah:

...why adding $~2k\pi~$ give us roots ? 
i.e root where k=1 and k=2... etc. 
write Geometric interpretation if you have.

Easier for me to give an algebraic elaboration.
The first question to consider is: 
for $~a \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},$ 
what are the $~a~$ distinct roots of the equation $~z^a = 1$ ?
For all $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},~$
let $~\xi_k~$ denote $~e^{i2k\pi/a}.$
Then, you have that for any $~m \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ that:
$$\xi_{(k + am)} = \exp\left[ ~\frac{i2(k + am)\pi}{a} ~\right] = \exp\left[ ~\frac{i2k\pi}{a} + i2m\pi ~\right]$$
$$
= e^{i(2k\pi)/a} \times e^{i2m\pi} = e^{i(2k\pi/a)} \times 1 = e^{i(2k\pi/a)} = \xi_k.
$$
Then you have that:

$(\xi_k)^a = \exp[ ~(i2k\pi/a) \times a ~] = \exp[ ~i2k\pi ~] = e^{i2k\pi} = 1.$

$\xi_0, ~\xi_1, ~\cdots, ~\xi_{a-1} ~$ represent $~a~$ distinct complex numbers.

$\xi_0 = \xi_{(0 + a)} = \xi_{(0 + 2a)} = \cdots.$ 
$\xi_1 = \xi_{(1 + a)} = \xi_{(1 + 2a)} = \cdots.$ 
$\xi_2 = \xi_{(2 + a)} = \xi_{(2 + 2a)} = \cdots.$ 
$\cdots.$ 


So, restricting $~k~$ to the elements in the set $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,a-1\},~$ generates the $~a~$ distinct values
$ ~\xi_0, ~\xi_1, ~\cdots, ~\xi_{a-1}.$
Therefore, the $~a~$ distinct roots of the equation $~z^a = 1,~$ are given by
$$\xi_0, ~\xi_1, ~\cdots, ~\xi_{a-1} ~: ~\xi_k = e^{i2k\pi/a}.$$
Now, suppose that $~Z~$ is some fixed non-zero complex number.  
Then, there exists  $~r \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~ \theta \in \Bbb{R} ~$ such that $~Z = re^{i\theta}.~$
Define
$$W = r^{1/a} \times e^{i\theta/a} \implies W^a = Z.$$
Now, consider the $~a~$ distinct values given by
$$(~W \times \xi_0 ~), ~( ~W \times \xi_1 ~), ~\cdots, ~( ~W \times \xi_{a-1} ~).$$
These $~a~$ distinct values may be re-expressed as
$$( ~W \times \xi_k ~) ~: ~k \in \{0,1,\cdots,a-1\}.$$
Then, you have that
$$( ~W \times \xi_k ~)^a = W^a \times (\xi_k)^a = Z \times 1 = Z.$$
This explains why, when $~Z = re^{i\theta},~$ that the $~a~$ distinct roots of the equation $~w^a = Z~$ are given by
$$r^{1/a} \times e^{i\theta/a} \times e^{i2k\pi/a}$$
$$= r^{1/a} \times e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)/a},$$
where $~k~$ is any element in $~\{0,1,\cdots,a-1\}.$

Great answer but why adding $ 2k\pi $give us roots ?  i.e root where k=1  and k=2... etc , write Geometric interpretation if you have .

@AzamAbdullah See Addendum-2 that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Thank you , to be serious I still have some questions maybe ask them in future ، thank you

I presume that you are trying to prove that if $z = r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ (and $r \ge 0$), then
$\{ w | w^n = z \} = \{ \sqrt[n]{r} \cos {\theta + 2 \pi k \over n} + i \sin {\theta + 2 \pi k \over n} | k=0,...,n-1 \}$.
The key result is that if $r, \rho \ge 0$, then
$(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta ) = (\rho \cos \phi, \rho \sin \phi )$ iff $r=\rho$ and either $r=0$ or $\phi = \theta+2 \pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Consequently, if $w^n = (\rho \cos \phi + i\rho \sin \phi )^n = z = r \cos \theta + ir \sin \theta$, then $\rho = \sqrt[n]{r}$ and (if $r>0$) $n \phi = \theta + 2 \pi k$, which is where the $\phi = {\theta + 2 \pi k \over n}$ come from.
Since $\cos, \sin$ are $2 \pi $ periodic, it should be clear that we need only consider $k=0,...,n-1$.

Great answer but why adding $ 2k\pi$ give us roots ?  i.e root where k=1  and k=2... etc , write Geometric interpretation if you have .

Perhaps review the key result above?

For example:
$(\cos \frac {2\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac {2\pi}{3})^3 = (-\frac 12 + i\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}) ^3 = 1$ and
$(\cos \frac {4\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac {4\pi}{3})^3 = (-\frac 12 - i\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}) ^3 = 1$ and
$(\cos \frac {6\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac {6\pi}{3})^3 = (1) ^3 = 1$
$z^3 = 1$ has three solutions.
And extrapolating further $z^n = 1$ has $n$ solutions.
Does this mean that $1^\frac 13$ has 3 values?  or $z^\frac 1a$ has $a$ different values?
In some sense it does, but when we use the $z^\frac 1a$ we almost always mean the "principal root."
Which is the one we get when we use the smallest $\theta$ we can in
$(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^\frac 1a$

Good work but that is'nt my question , I do'nt say if 1 ^ ⅓ , has different values instead I meant why this formula true ? Why changing k give root of z ?
